# PLSQL execute immediate ORA-00955 name is already used by an existing object

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have made an PL/SQL block which creates an table if it does not exist. If it exist then it truncates the table. When i execute the script i get the following error:

```
ORA-00955 name is already used by an existing object
```

Can you please help me to solve this error?

**SCRIPT**

```
DECLARE
nCount NUMBER;
vSqlStatement LONG;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(1) into nCount FROM all_tables where table_name = 'CHANGES'; 
    IF(nCount <= 0)
    THEN
       dbms_output.put_line (' Greather or equal to 0: ' || nCount);     
       vSqlStatement:='
       CREATE TABLE ADMRAPPORT.CHANGES
       (
            "ID" NUMBER(10),
            "VersionName" VARCHAR2(255),
            "VersionNumber" NUMBER(10),
            "Version_ID" NUMBER(10),
            "VersionFlag" VARCHAR2(255)
        )';
      execute immediate vSqlStatement;    
    END IF;
    IF(nCount > 0)
    THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (' Smaller then 0');
        vSqlStatement:='TRUNCATE TABLE ADMRAPPORT.CHANGES';
        execute immediate vSqlStatement;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Hint:  `ADMRAPPORT`.

Comment: You are not testing the data dictionary for the name of your `changes` table - it is therefore perfectly possibly that an object with this name resides in `admrapport`. NB: The text outputs do not match your conditions

Comment: Hi Gordon i don't understand your comment, can you please explain?

Comment: Hi collapser, i improve the question but still i get the same error!

Comment: What do you get back from "SELECT * FROM all_tables where table_name = 'CHANGES'"?

Comment: Hi Stilgar i get 0 back as result

Comment: Can you also try `SELECT * FROM all_objects where object_name = 'CHANGES'`?

Comment: Hi Kaushik Still te same

Comment: What database are you running your `select` query on? Is it the same one that you are running `create table` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would all be a lot simpler if could run the script as the `ADMRAPPORT` user and remove references to the schema name.

Currently you check `ALL_TABLES` for any table named `CHANGES` belonging to any schema. `ALL_TABLES` only shows you tables you have access to, which means tables that have been granted to you or to a role you have. Two ways this could go wrong:

1. Some other schema (not `ADMRAPPORT`) has a table named `CHANGES` and grants you access to it. Your count result will be 1 so your code will stop without creating `ADMRAPPORT.CHANGES`.
2. `ADMRAPPORT.CHANGES` does in fact exist but it's not granted to you, so your count result is 0 because the table isn't shown in `ALL_TABLES`. Then the code goes ahead and tries to create it, which fails. Maybe this is what's happening here.

If you can call the script as the `ADMRAPPORT` user, try this simplified version:

```
declare
    object_already_exists exception;
    pragma exception_init(object_already_exists, -955);

    vsqlstatement long :=
       'create table changes
       ( id            number(10)
       , versionname   varchar2(255)
       , versionnumber number(10)
       , version_id    number(10)
       , versionflag   varchar2(255) )';

begin
    execute immediate vsqlstatement;
    dbms_output.put_line('Table created');
exception
    when object_already_exists then
        execute immediate 'truncate table changes';
        dbms_output.put_line('Table truncated.');
end;
```

I would also add some constraints (is `ID` the primary key? should any columns be `NOT NULL`? etc), and consider grants and synonyms as well.

Note I have removed the double-quotes from your column names, because those just create confusion and bugs later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DBA_OBJECTS instead of ALL_TABLES. If you don't have access to this table, then you have to handle exception as suggested by William

Answer (score -1):

Did you copy/paste the script correctly?  For example, you have:

```
IF(nCount <= 0)
    THEN
       dbms_output.put_line (' Greather or equal to 0: ' || nCount);
```

and later

```
IF(nCount > 0)
    THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (' Smaller then 0');
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but this doesn't really answer the question, even though you are right that the comments are the wrong way around (and misspelled).

Comment: Thanks @WilliamRobertson , it actually might explain the situation if the actual code that was executed had the condition block reversed (as the comments suggest), meaning the create table statement was in the block where the count was greater than 0.  Anyway, sometimes I wonder why I even bother ;-)